# from compile co_code back to executable is there any way to convert your python program to a hexadecimal string and back?

Tags: python

Is there any way in python to transform co_code back to the outcome of compile?
I would like to store my program in an hexadecimal string so that i can compare that each node in the network runs the same program
Or can we execute co_code with something like exec?

Answer (score 0):

```
from json import loads, dumps
from binascii import unhexlify
with open('compile.py') as c:
    sjfhg = bytes(c.read().encode()).hex()
    exec(compile(unhexlify(sjfhg).decode(), '', 'exec'))
```

Comment: It would be useful to have some context information for your answer, why and how does it work, not just a plain piece of code. If you clan, please edit your answer.